# Finding the basis for the kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have no idea how to solve this problem, honestly. Help would be appreciated.

> Define a linear transformation $T \, \colon \mathbb P_2 \to \mathbb R^3$ by $T(p) = \begin{bmatrix} p(0)\\ p(-1)\\ p(-1) \end{bmatrix}$.
>
> a. Find a basis for the kernel of $T$.
>
> b. Describe the range of $T$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Do you understand all the terminology being used (for instance: what a basis is, what a "kernel" is)? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: Honestly, how to start it. I dont understand how to put T(p) into a matrix form since no function is given in the problem. It also doesn't tell us to use the standard basis for P2. So any example on how to do this would be great.

Comment: You don't need matrices at all for this. Which polynomials are in the kernel of $T$?

Comment: This is the only thing given in the problem. Thats why i am confused. But without the polynomials, I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: A polynomial $p$ is in the kernel if and only if $p(0) = 0$ and $p(-1) = 0$, right? What does the factorization of such a polynomial look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's how to put $T$ into matrix form. Let $\beta = \left\{1, x, x^2 \right\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb P_2.$ We know that a linear transformation is completely determined by how it acts on the basis vectors. So we compute $T(1), T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$ and construct our matrix from these. We have 
$$T(1) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]\text{,  } \hspace{3mm} T(x) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{array} \right], \hspace{3mm} \text{ and } \hspace{3mm} T(x^2) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right].$$ 
Therefore, the matrix of the above linear transformation is 
$$[T] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1&-1&1 \\ 1&-1&1  \end{array} \right].$$ 
Can you take the question from here?